# Ajax not working on server, but on local is working perfectly

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is my code...

```
$('.savebtn').click(function () {
    var idComment = $(this).attr('idComment');
    var content = $("#area" + idComment + "").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'update_comment.php?idComment=' + idComment + '&content=' + content + ''
    });
    //$("#area"+idComment+"").val(content);
    $("#editarea" + idComment + "").hide();
    location.reload();
});
```

Comment: what exactly is _not working_?

Comment: What for method is the server waiting? Post or get?

Comment: The ajax code.. First I thought it was something wrong with the update_comment.php, but it isn't. I guess it is something wrong with the server. I am using free web hosting(http://www.000webhost.com/)

Comment: it seems that 'update_comment.php' path is incorrect. Open google chrome inspector F12, open the network tab, make the ajax call and see if the 'update_comment.php' script is called

Comment: on server are you sure `update_comment.php` it is located in same folder where you have written this code. And also please try to alert something to test whether click event is occur or not and also see is there any error in console

Comment: try to inspect the response of your ajax call with something like Chrome Inspector (net tab with xhr filter) and see what the server's answer is.

Comment: The whole project works perfect on local machine.. On server works everything except update comment...

Comment: @user2489797 post the full web url to your project and let me see.

Comment: http://blogmember.vacau.com/

Comment: @user2489797 you mean to say request to `update_comment.php` is successfull  but sql update query is not working ?

Comment: update query is working. Everything is wokring on local machine. When I uploaded on server, updating comment isn't working

Comment: can you edit your question and put you `update_comment.php` code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you provide so little information on the "*not working*", I have to make assumptions. This is where I believe is the root of the problem:

`$.ajax()` is an asynchronous call, that means, code that is below `$.ajax()` will get executed even it `$.ajax()` hasn't finished yet. In your case: `location.reload();` might get executed before `$.ajax()` was successfull. If that is the case, your ajax-request will get cancelled before it was able to finish.

Solution: put all the code that relies on the `$.ajax()` being successfull or to be finished inside a success-handler:

```
$('.savebtn').click(function () {
    var idComment = $(this).attr('idComment');
    var content = $("#area" + idComment + "").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'update_comment.php?idComment=' + idComment + '&content=' + content + '',
        success: function() { // this code will be executed when your ajax-call has finished successfully
            location.reload();
        },
    });
    //$("#area"+idComment+"").val(content);
    $("#editarea" + idComment + "").hide();
});
```

Comment: That's the answer.. It's working.. Thank you very much!!